# Command line client for Github Search

Tags: linux, command-line, github

I need a command line client for [Githubs Search API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/). What would you recommend?

Requirements:

- Ubuntu
- preferable plain executable (without need to install via `npm`)
- easy and full featured command line interface

Already looked at:

- [github-search-repos-cli](https://github.com/kevva/github-search-repos-cli) (requires `npm`)
- [gh-search-cli](https://github.com/feinoujc/gh-search-cli) (requires `npm`)
- [github-searcher-cli](https://github.com/jaebradley/github-searcher-cli) (requires `npm`)

Comment: If all 3 of the choices presented meet the requirements, what features are you looking for?

Comment: All require to have nodejs and npm installed. I'd prefer a plain executable. I'm also not aware of the cli differences w.r.t. usability.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Perhaps a small edit to your question might help make it a little more clear the "possible choices" are actually undesirable because you would prefer a plain executable.  Maybe just change "possible choices" to "already looked at", or something similar.

Comment: Please clarify what the output should look like.  That is, whether or not the output should be an *HTML* file, or launch a browser to view that, or should the output should be text on *STDOUT*.